# Ambiguous call for overloaded function templates - even if one is more specialized?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, overloading

Consider the following:

```
#include <utility>

template <int N>
using size_ = std::integral_constant<int, N>; 

template <int From>
void f(size_<From>, size_<From+1> ) // (1)
{ }

template <int From, int To>   // (2)
void f(size_<From>, size_<To> )
{ }

int main()
{
    f(size_<0>{}, size_<1>{});
}
```

Both gcc and clang report the call as ambiguous. Why? Isn't `(1)` more specialized than `(2)`?

Note: I know this is easily fixable with an extra `enable_if_t<(To > From+1)>` thrown into `(2)`, but I wouldn't have thought I needed to do that.

Comment: Isn't it because `From+1` is non-deducible, hence deduction itself *succeeds* when verified against some unique values like `size_<N>{}, size_<M>{}` generated from overload (2) ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki §14.8.2.4/11: "In most cases, all template parameters must have values in order for deduction to succeed, but for partial ordering purposes a template parameter may remain without a value provided it is not used in the types being used for partial ordering. [ *Note*: **A template parameter used in a non-deduced context is considered used.** — *end note* ]"

Answer (score 3):

This was - unsurprisingly - addressed by a similar example in a CWG issue, namely [**#455**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#455):

> In case that one of the arguments is non-deuced then partial ordering
>   should only consider the type from the specialization:
>
> ```
> template<typename T> struct B { typedef T type; };
>
> template<typename T> char* f3(T, T);                   // #7
> template<typename T> long* f3(T, typename B<T>::type); // #8
>
> char* p3 = f3(p3, p3); // #9
> ```
>
> According to my reasoning #9 should yield ambiguity since second pair
>   is (T, long*). The second type (i.e. long*) was taken from the
>   specialization candidate of #8. EDG and GCC accepted the code. VC and
>   BCC found an ambiguity.

Both ICC and VC++ compile your code. According to current wording, they are correct: **Each pair is handled independently**, and as `size_<From+1>` makes `From` appear in a non-deduced context ([temp.deduct.type]/(5.3)), deduction necessarily fails, and hence `size_<From+1>` is at least as specialized as `size_<To>` but not vice versa. Thus overload (1) is more specialized than (2).

So ICC and VC++ (presumably) process every deduction pair and conclude that, for the second one, `size_<To>` is not at least as specialized as `size_<From+1>`.
Clang and GCC (presumably) argue that, for (1), `From` is deduced from the first argument, and thus need not be deduced in the second pair for `size_<To>` to be at leas as specialized as its counterpart.

Comment: In hindsight, that example has not that much to do with the example in question...

Comment: @Barry I'd say so, yes. It would surprise me if not.

Comment: I'm just curious - which section states that corresponding pairs are handled independently?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki I suppose [temp.deduct.partial]/8 suffices: *"Otherwise, using the resulting types `P` and `A`, the deduction is then done as described in 14.8.2.5."*

Comment: @Columbo I submitted as [67426](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=67426), but I'm not even entirely sure it's a bug. It may be that the non-deduced pair is simply ignored so the (2) --> (1) deduction effectively just works off of the first pair (which trivially succeeds).

Comment: @Barry That would be correct if #1391's resolution was to be accepted, but that didn't happen yet (and hopefully won't as-is).

Comment: I guess trying to make sense of this is impossible without comparing different existing implementations and chosing somewhere midway. I've seen too much interpretations of these sections to still think that one could actually come to a conclusion based on reading and arguing with the spec text. 10 years after DR 455 people are still left guessing

Comment: If I were to guess, I can see how Clang's behavior makes sense because the actual type deduction by 14.8.2.5 cannot compare `Foo<I>` with `Foo<NonDeducibleExpr>` and would leave it alone. The parent deduction process (14.8.2.1, 14.8.2.3 or a partial specialization etc) would substitute into the non-deducible expr and do the final comparison to check for a match. Partial ordering would not do the final substitution and comparison, which would lead to clang's behavior (it will have deduced `From` and be lucky).

Comment: But then, I cannot find any real evidence that it works like this, I wish that it would be more clearly described.